# Error en python desconocido. builtins.ValueError: Command is not a valid bot command

Tags: python, telegram

Hola buenas si alguien me puede echar una mano con mi codigo python:

```
import scrapMoha #importo un codigo de python que tengo creado para poder mostrar una lista.
import logging
from telegram.ext import Updater, CommandHandler, MessageHandler, Filters

#Habilito el login
logging.basicConfig(format='%(asctime)s - %(name)s - %(levelname)s - %(message)s',
                    level=logging.INFO)

logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)

#Al hacer click en iniciar saludamos al usuario
def iniciar(update, context):
    """Aqui le mandamos el mensaje"""
    update.message.reply_text('''Hola soy un bot creado por Moha de M03 1 de DAW.
Escribe /ayuda para que veas lo que puedo hacer :D, espero ayudarte.''')

def ayudar(update, context):
    """Aqui digo lo que sabe hacer mi bot"""
    update.message.reply_text('Help!')

def sumar(update, context):
    try:
        numero1 = int(context.args[0])
        numero2 = int(context.args[1])

        suma = numero1 + numero2
        update.message.reply_text('La suma es '+str(suma))

    except (IndexError, ValueError):
        update.message.reply_text('Por favor utiliza dos numeros')

def dividir(update, context):
    try:
        numero1 = int(context.args[0])
        numero2 = int(context.args[1])

        div= numero1 / numero2
        update.message.reply_text('La division da '+str(div))

    except (IndexError, ValueError):
        update.message.reply_text('Por favor utiliza dos numeros')


def coronaStats(IndexError, ValueError):
    update.message.reply_text(scrapMoha.test())
def main():
    """Aqui iniciamos el bot y lo que hacemos es crear un token para poder iniciar el bot en telegram"""
    sesion = Updater("Token de mi bot de telegram", use_context=True)
    # el token lo guardamos en un a variable llamada botm3
    botm3 = sesion.dispatcher
    # on different commands - answer in Telegram
    botm3.add_handler(CommandHandler("Iniciar", iniciar))
    botm3.add_handler(CommandHandler("Ayuda", ayudar))
    botm3.add_handler(CommandHandler("Sumar", sumar))
    botm3.add_handler(CommandHandler("dividir", dividir))
    botm3.add_handler(CommandHandler("Estadistica general.", coronaStats))
    #Aqui empieza el bot
    sesion.start_polling()

    #Aqui decimos que es un bulce y que no pare hasta que le demos a ctrl+c 
    sesion.idle()
if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

En mi codigo python de scrapMoha tengo este codigo, el cual lo que hace es ir a una pagina web la trata y lo que hace es coger los valores de los enfermos del Covid-19 y luego la guardo en un def para poder luego pasarlo al mi bot de Telegram:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests
import pandas as pd  
pd.set_option('display.max_rows', None) 
pd.set_option('display.max_columns', None)
pd.set_option('display.width', None)
url = 'https://alcorconhoy.com/estadisticas-coronavirus-covid-19'
pagina = requests.get(url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(pagina.content, 'html.parser') 
cud= soup.findAll('div', class_='td-covid-country-name') 
ciudades=list() 
for i in cud:
    ciudades.append(i.text) 
cf= soup.findAll('div', class_='td-covid-confirmed')
casosConfirmados=list()
for i in cf:                                                            
    casosConfirmados.append(i.text)
mt= soup.findAll('div', class_='td-covid-deaths')
muertes=list()
for i in mt:
    muertes.append(i.text)
recu= soup.findAll('div', class_='td-covid-recovered')
recuperados=list()
for i in recu:
    recuperados.append(i.text)
ca= soup.findAll('div', class_='td-covid-active')
casosActivos=list()
for i in ca:
    casosActivos.append(i.text)
ciudades.pop(0) 
casosConfirmados.pop(0) 
muertes.pop(0)
recuperados.pop(0)
casosActivos.pop(0)
def corona():
    resultadofinal= pd.DataFrame({'Ciudad':ciudades,'Casos Confirmados':casosConfirmados,'Muertes':muertes,'Casos Recuperados':recuperados,'Casos Activos':casosActivos})
    return resultadofinal
```

Yo lo que quiero hacer es importar el resultado final que es un diccionario con clave y valores y quiero que el bot de Telegram responda con ese diccionario pero a la hora de ejecutar el codigo principal (es el primer codigo que he puesto), me da un error que es el seguiente:

```
builtins.ValueError: Command is not a valid bot command
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Vale ya tengo la solución es un fallo pequeño en la linea donde llamo al comando para el bot, pues esta provocado el fallo ya que al pone un nombre con espacio lo entiendo como un comando cuando realmente no lo es.
Entonces la solución es corregir esto:

```
def main():
    """Aqui iniciamos el bot y lo que hacemos es crear un token para poder iniciar el bot en telegram"""
    sesion = Updater("Token de mi bot de telegram", use_context=True)
    # el token lo guardamos en un a variable llamada botm3
    botm3 = sesion.dispatcher
    # on different commands - answer in Telegram
    botm3.add_handler(CommandHandler("Iniciar", iniciar))
    botm3.add_handler(CommandHandler("Ayuda", ayudar))
    botm3.add_handler(CommandHandler("Sumar", sumar))
    botm3.add_handler(CommandHandler("dividir", dividir))
    **botm3.add_handler(CommandHandler("Estadistica general.", coronaStats)) #!Aqui es donde falla**
    #Aqui empieza el bot
    sesion.start_polling()

    #Aqui decimos que es un bulce y que no pare hasta que le demos a ctrl+c 
    sesion.idle()
```

A esto, el cambio es pequeño ya que lo que hago es borrar un espacio exactamente donde pone **botm3.add_handler(CommandHandler("Estadistica genereal.", coronaStats))** a ***botm3.add_handler(CommandHandler("Estadistica", coronaStats))*** os dejo la corrección por si a alguien le pasa :D.
La corrección és:

```
botm3.add_handler(CommandHandler("Estadistica genereal.", coronaStats))
    def main():
        """Aqui iniciamos el bot y lo que hacemos es crear un token para poder iniciar el bot en telegram"""
        sesion = Updater("Token de mi bot de telegram", use_context=True)
        # el token lo guardamos en un a variable llamada botm3
        botm3 = sesion.dispatcher
        # on different commands - answer in Telegram
        botm3.add_handler(CommandHandler("Iniciar", iniciar))
        botm3.add_handler(CommandHandler("Ayuda", ayudar))
        botm3.add_handler(CommandHandler("Sumar", sumar))
        botm3.add_handler(CommandHandler("dividir", dividir))
        botm3.add_handler(CommandHandler("Estadistica", coronaStats)) #Aqui esta corregido.
        #Aqui empieza el bot
        sesion.start_polling()

        #Aqui decimos que es un bulce y que no pare hasta que le demos a ctrl+c 
        sesion.idle()
```